# What is the difference between parcel serve vs parcel build when it comes to bundling?

Tags: bundler, parceljs

Hi Im new to Parcel and trying to migrate an existing project from Webpack. I was able to quickly get things working until I realised that I get a `module` not found error.

This error only shows up in `parcel build`.
I noticed a circular import and fixed it.

**My question, why didn't `parcel serve` have an issue?** I use that command to start the dev server and run my e2e tests. But in this case my e2e tests all passed. So now I feel like I can't rely on it.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the exact same issue where I reference a local module that imports 3rd party libraries. Parcel serve works fine on first run but parcel build fails. If parcel serve is run first then parcel build works. Can do automated builds till this is resolved

Comment: @sumo i think i did something like run parcel build and the use something like the serve package to serve the dist folder and ran the tests against that.